# Jade lang getting variable back from javascript

Tags: pug

I know how to pass Jade variable into Javascript code using syntax like this:

`var jsVar = "#{bladeVar}"`

But now, I need a way to get javascript variable (take from DOM) back into Jade but I'm struggling for hours : [[.

How could I do this?

Comment: you straight up can't, if you're rendering jade serverside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer what you mean: you can not do it.

Jade is compiled on server side, (local nodejs is count as server side as well) so you can not use a JS variable from a script, that will run only the client side, simply because it is not running where you create your markup from jade.

If you would like to use a variable during render, then you can to things like in this example:

```
p Hello
-var world = "world"
p Hello #{world}!
-world = "Hello world!" //what javascript you write here, it will be executed during render.
p #{world}
script(type='text/javascript').
      document.write("this will compile when the client gets it, not while render!");
      document.write(world); // undefined
```